# Convert Table data in a array to multiple objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, javascript-objects, name-value

I have an array

```
data = [

    0 3x abcd aezakmi 900 
    1 2x defg panjer 800
    2 1x hijk  flyhigh 750

]
```

I want to convert it to this

```
data = [
 [`{0}{3x}{abcd}{aezakmi}{900}`]
 [`{1}{2x}{defg}{panjer}{900}`]
 [`{2}{1x}{jijk}{flyhigh}{700}`]
]
```

so that I can map them easily in the table.

Comment: Where's this "data" coming from? Any you haven't posted any JavaScript or arrays in your question.

Comment: this data is coming from an api response, I want to convert that data from that format to this format.

Comment: First. your array data is in wrong format. Make sure that the data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I changed array, because he had syntax error. Maybe this code is not ideal, but he work.

```js
data = [
  '0 3x abcd aezakmi 900',
  '1 2x defg panjer 800',
  '2 1x hijk flyhigh 750',
];

const separate = (data) => {
  const arr = [];
  data.forEach((el) => {
    const obj = {};
    let i = 0;
    el.split(' ').forEach((el2) => {
      i += 1
      obj[i] = el2;
    })
    arr.push(`{${obj[1]}}{${obj[2]}}{${obj[3]}}{${obj[4]}}{${obj[5]}}`)
  });
  return arr;
};

console.log(separate(data));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).